# "storefront-handheld-footer-bar" missing when using child theme WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

I'm having a strange issue with a website I'm building in Wordpress.

I'm using the WooCommerce Storefront theme with a custom child theme.

For some reason on mobile devices, the fixed element - "storefront-handheld-footer-bar" is missing from the bottom of the page.

So far I have done the following to try and figure out the issue:

- Checked to see if anything in my CSS may be hiding it, there doesn't
  appear to be anything hiding it
- Checked that I haven't disabled in in the child themes functions file
- Checked the source to see if it's actually rendering, which it isn;t
- Activated the parent theme Storefront, this shows the footer bar but
  obviously doesn't fix my issue.
- Done some searching on the internet but there doesn't seem to be a
  fix anywhere.

Here's a [link to the website](https://www.littlegreentree.co.uk/)

I was hoping to launch today but this has thrown a spanner in the works!

I'm not sure where to go from here so really this is to see if anyone has come across the same issue and if they have potential solutions that I could try. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you customized footer and removed some storefront's action calls

here is an original code

```
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="col-full">

            <?php
            /**
             * Functions hooked in to storefront_footer action
             *
             * @hooked storefront_footer_widgets - 10
             * @hooked storefront_credit         - 20
             */
            do_action( 'storefront_footer' );
            ?>

        </div><!-- .col-full -->
    </footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

Footer bar is called from the storefront_footer action, here is the hook

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
```

So, your choice is either calling `do_action('storefront_footer)` or manually calling `storefront_handheld_footer_bar()` function somwhere in your footer.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that schoolboy error. Thanks Andrei, that has sorted my problem.